# ReactNative when appcilation download after only comes on first open Page(Signup after Login)

Tags: react-native

I have +10 pages . But I want to when download Appcilation and first open just come Signup page(+ after signup) to Login page . After the selected Infomation page and open to Profile page .
My question is when download to first time  get Signup page. And  after  when every open appcilation user will see Profile page .
how do i do this ? I have router page and navigations process.

```
Pages forexample : 
Signup.js
Login.js
InformationCreate.js
Profile.js
```